# Output the page URL in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

How can I get the current page's URL?

I have tried:

```
{{ site.url }}
```

But this fails to out put anything.

Comment: You need to define that in your `_config.yml`. It's empty by default. Once defined you might want something like `{{site.url}}{{page.url}}` to get the hole path.

Comment: Great thanks, how can I combine {{site.url}}{{page.url}} to one var so I can pass it in to a liquid function?

Comment: `{% capture url_path %}{{site.url}}{{page.url}}{% endcapture %}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to define that in your `_config.yml`.

It's empty by default.

Once defined you might want something like `{{site.url}}{{page.url}}` to get the whole path.

To capture the whole path in a variable you can use

`{% capture url_path %}{{site.url}}{{page.url}}{% endcapture %}`

Answer (score 2):

It can work out of the box in GitHub Pages at least using `{{ page.url | absolute_url }}`. See [Page Variables doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page-variables) in conjunction with the [Absolute URL filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#:%7E:text=Absolute%20URL).